# Precision recall in lucene java

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine

I want to use Lucene to calculate Precision and Recall.

I did these steps:

1. Made some index files. To do this I used indexer code and indexed `.txt` files which exist in this path `C:/inn` (there are 4 text files in this folder) and take them in "outt" folder by setting the indexpath to `C:/outt` in the Indexer code.
2. Created a package called `lia.benchmark` and a class inside it which is called "PrecisionRecall" and add `externaljars` (rightclick --> Java build path --> add external jars) and added `Lucene-benchmark-.3.2.0jar` and `Lucene-core-3.3.0jar`
3. Set the `topicsfile` path in code to `C:/lia2e/src/lia/benchmark/topics.txt` and
   `qrelsfile` to `C:/lia2e/src/lia/benchmark/qrels.txt` and dir to "C:/outt".

   Here is code:

   ```
   package lia.benchmark;        
   import java.io.File;  
   import java.io.PrintWriter;  
   import java.io.BufferedReader;  
   import java.io.FileReader;  
   import org.apache.lucene.search.*;  
   import org.apache.lucene.store.*;  
   import org.apache.lucene.benchmark.quality.*;  
   import org.apache.lucene.benchmark.quality.utils.*;  
   import org.apache.lucene.benchmark.quality.trec.*;  

    public class PrecisionRecall {  

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {  

     File topicsFile = new File("C:/lia2e/src/lia/benchmark/topics.txt");  
            File qrelsFile = new File("C:/lia2e/src/lia/benchmark/qrels.txt");  
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:/outt"));  
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);  

            String docNameField = "filename";  

            PrintWriter logger = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);  

            TrecTopicsReader qReader = new TrecTopicsReader();   
            QualityQuery qqs[] = qReader.readQueries(                        
                    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(topicsFile)));  

            Judge judge = new TrecJudge(new BufferedReader(          
                   new FileReader(qrelsFile)));                                          

            judge.validateData(qqs, logger);                                          

            QualityQueryParser qqParser = new SimpleQQParser("title", "contents");  

            QualityBenchmark qrun = new QualityBenchmark(qqs, qqParser, searcher, docNameField);  
      SubmissionReport submitLog = null;  
            QualityStats stats[] = qrun.execute(judge,                   
                      submitLog, logger);  

           QualityStats avg = QualityStats.average(stats);          
           avg.log("SUMMARY",2,logger, "  ");  
      dir.close();  
     }  
   }
   ```
4. Initialized qrels and topics. In documents folder (C:\inn) I have 4 txt files which  2 of them is relevance to my query ( query is apple) so I filled qrels and topics.

   the qrels file like this:

   ```
   <top>  
       <num> Number: 0 
       <title> apple
       <desc> Description:  
       <narr> Narrative:  
   </top>
   ```

   and  topics file like this:

   ```
   0    0      789.txt           1
   0    0      101.txt           1
   ```

   I tried also the Path format namely for example "C:\inn\789.txt"  instead of  "789.txt" 
   but results are  zero:

   ```
   0 - contents:apple
   0 Stats:
   Search Seconds: 0.016
   DocName Seconds: 0.000
   Num Points: 2.000
   Num Good Points: 0.000
   Max Good Points: 2.000
   Average Precision: 0.000
   MRR: 0.000
   Recall: 0.000
   Precision At 1: 0.000
   SUMMARY
   Search Seconds: 0.016
   DocName Seconds: 0.000
   Num Points: 2.000
   Num Good Points: 0.000
   Max Good Points: 2.000
   Average Precision: 0.000
   MRR: 0.000
   Recall: 0.000
   Precision At 1: 0.000
   ```

Can you tell me what is wrong with me?

I really need to know why results are zero.

Comment: As a general debugging technique, if you don't get output that you expect, work backwards and interrogate the values earlier and earlier in your program until you find values that you *do* expect.  That way you can figure out exactly where things are going wrong.

Comment: I don't know about Lucene, but isn't it necessary to close the <num> <title> <desc> and <narr> tags at the qrels file?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that the `qrels.txt` format is wrong: [the javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_0/api/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/quality/trec/TrecJudge.html) suggests the following:

Expected input format:

```
 qnum  0   doc-name     is-relevant
```

Two sample lines:

```
 19    0   doc303       1
 19    0   doc7295      0
```

(I know it's 2.3.0 javadoc, but the format wasn't changed in 3.0)

So it seems that you've swapped the files: `TrecTopicsReader` expects what you have in `qrels.txt`; `TrecJudge` expects what you have in `topics.txt`.